# Webgl drawing two different geometries with two different vbo

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

Say you have an array of vbo.
You create, bind and fill the first and then on with the others.

At draw time you rebind them and define how gl must extract the data with attribpointer.

My code works fine if I fill one buffer with all geometries but now I would like to experiment with separate buffers for each geometry.

From what I've read, at the end, when all the state machine are set, you can call drawArrays just once(eg in the draw loop).

The problem is that each vbo has different number of vertices, so I'm confused about what paramter
to pass at drawarrays:

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, THIS PARAMETER SHOULD TAKE CARE OF THE NUMBER OF VERTICES);
```

I've tried adding up the count of the vertices of each buffer but that gives me a index out of range error. But how can I deal with the fact that each vbo has a different number of vertices whereas we must use (or at least I think so) just one drawcall, in the drawloop?

EDIT: I've managed to get it working calling drawarrays for each vbo. I'm still not sure whether this is the optimal solution or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call drawArrays for each set of binds you do (once for each geometry).

The more optimal solution would be to use the [VertexArrayObject](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.7.15) and then collect the bindings in those:

for each mesh you can bind like so:

```
vao = gl.createVertexArray();

gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
//gl.bindAttribute calls 
gl.bindVertexArray(null);
```

then when drawing for each mesh you can then do:

```
gl.bindVertexArray(mesh.vao);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.pointCount);
gl.bindVertexArray(null);
```